# Mongoengine.django not found

Tags: python, django, mongodb, python-3.x

Python ver=3.4

Django ver=1.9.2

In my project I am trying to integrate mongodb with above django version I have installed the mongoengine in my virtual environment and have made the necessary [image: changes] in settings.py file.

I am able to start the server but when I try to run the project in the browser it notifies me

> A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

and in the terminal [image: this error] shows up.

Please tell me the correct way to integrate the mongodb if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so your issue lies in the version of mongoengine you are using. I am using the version 0.8.7 and it has `mongoengine.django` but the latest version on [Github](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine) (0.10.6) has this deprecated.

> Django support has been split from the main MongoEngine repository.
>   The legacy Django extension may be found bundled with the 0.9 release
>   of MongoEngine.

source -> http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/django.html